# What's the simplest way to manage dependencies in Android app repositories?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, ant

I want to make an Android app which is dependent on other 3rd-party libraries, namely [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock), and track the app's development in source control using Git. I also want to make it easy for other developers to help me work on the app. Developers should be able to build the app in one or two simple steps.

I would like to develop the app in the simplest environment possible. I have tried to use [Android Maven Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), and I have tried to setup Maven integration in Eclipse. I find the process very unintuitive and needlessly complicated.

Is it possible to manage project dependencies using Git submodules, and use a very simple build system, perhaps based on Ant, to link any dependencies, debug, install, and sign/deploy the `.apk`?

Ideally, I would like to do something like the following:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:me/myapp.git # clone the repo
$ cd myapp # enter the app directory
$ git submodule init && git submodule update # initialize dependencies
$ ant debug install # build & run app
```

In addition, I would like to be able to develop the app in an IDE. The IDE should have intellisense & autocompletion (Vim would work, but I would love something similar to how Eclipse automatically adds methods that must be overridden when creating a derived class). Building and running the app from the IDE should merely execute the appropriate Ant commands.

What is the simplest way of achieving something like the above setup? Namely:

1. Dependencies managed as submodules (or similar)
2. Simple build tool
3. IDE integrated with build tool & with autocompletion/intellisense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way to manage dependencies is the *default one* that Android SDK provides. I agree that Maven is very unintuitive and needlessly complicated. Moreover, Maven is not supported officially by Android team.

You just need a good VCS like Git or Mercurial.

- Put all `*.jar` files in sub folder `/libs`;
- In Eclipse, right click on project then choose <kbd>Refresh</kbd>;

To deploy the APK in `release` mode with command line, you just need an `ant.properties` like:

```
key.store=/path-to-key-store
key.alias=alias-name
key.store.password=password
key.alias.password=alias-password
```

And:

```
$ ant clean release
```

or,

```
$ ant clean release install
```

---

*Edit*

I'm sorry I forgot about Git submodules. I've never used Git before but just read [some info here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). I think submodules are like sub projects with source code. If so things are easy too. For example you have the host project `A` and a sub project `B` (which is a library):

```
A
|__ submodules
    |__ B
```

To include library `B`, open `A/project.properties` and add this line:

```
android.library.reference.1=submodules/B
```

or you can have Eclipse manage it by right clicking on `A`, select <kbd>Properties</kbd>, select <kbd>Android</kbd> tab, then add `B` to <kbd>Library</kbd> box.

Comment: Adding the `.jar` files to the project itself would mean they're tracked by Git. Also, they wouldn't be as easy to update as submodules, which can be updated by checking out the desired SHA. That being said, having Eclipse manage the class path seems like the simplest solution. I will mark this correct if no better answers turn up in the next few days.

Comment: @modocache Thanks. And I'm sorry for forgetting about Git submodules. I edited the answer.